# Typescript: error TS2693: 'Note' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use Typescript for my firebase project and i am getting the following errors.

```
 error TS2693: 'Note' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I used the following code

```
interface Note {
 image: string;
 name: string;
 pdf: string;
}

const itemname = Note.name;
```

But that doesn't seem to work

here is the imports

```
import {
AngularFirestore,
AngularFirestoreCollection,
AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

here is the other part

```
  export class Advance11Component implements OnInit {
  notesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Note>;
  notes: Observable<Note[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.notesCollection = this.afs
    .collection('class11AdvancedTheory')
    .doc(itemname)
    .collection(itemname, (ref) => {
      return ref;
    });
    this.notes = this.notesCollection.valueChanges();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean `type itemname = Note.name` or `const itemname: Note.name`. As the error suggests, `Note.name` is a type, and you're using it as a variable

Answer (score 2):

An `interface` (or `type`) can tell you the *shape* of something.

```
// A `tree` has a number of `branches`.
interface Tree {
  branches: number
}
```

An instance (e.g. `const x = ...`) assigns a specific value that can be reference at runtime.

```
// This `tree` has 34 `branches`.
const myTree: Tree = { branches: 34 }
```

You cannot mix these two during assignments. Taking your example, you would ask "How many `branches` does `myTreeBranches` have?" and it would say "`typeof Tree.branches` is `number`", information that is not useful or supported in JavaScript.

```
// Doesn't work
const myTreeBranches = Tree.branches // typeof `Tree.branches` is `number`.
```

You probably want one of these:

```
interface Tree {
    branches: number
}

type TreeBranches = Tree['branches'] // extract an interface property

const myTree: Tree = { branches: 34 } // create an instance of `Tree`

const myTreeBranches: Tree['branches'] = 34 // create variable that could be assigned to
                                            //    an instance of `Tree`
```